# Powershell: Filtering server list by the 2nd octet of the IP address

Tags: powershell, split, ip-address

I am trying to go through a list of servers for further querying via `WMI`. Unfortunately, if the scripts hits a server that cannot connect via `WMI`, it takes a long time before timing out.

These are generally servers in our DMZ, and allocated a specific address in the 2nd octet of the IP address, `.92` for example. So I am looking to filter out these servers as the first step in my query, so it can be ignore in any further `WMI` queries.

I have found many examples on how to do this, and again, I cannot use `WMI` methods as this defeats the object (eg: `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`).

In the example below, the server "SERVER" has an IP of `192.9.4.1` and I want to filter out all servers with ".9" in the second octet. so I use a simple `Test-Connection` cmdlet, and aim to split the result. Before I can split it, the result of the `Test-Connection` is:

```
$IP4Address = Test-Connection _Computer SERVER -Count 1 | Select IPV4Address

@{IPV4Address=192.9.4.1}
```

Which means that I need to count 19 chars from the beginning to get my "9".
IPV4Address

```
  $Octet = $IP4Address -split ("") 
  If ($Octet[19] -eq '9') 
    {write-host "In DMZ"} 
  Else
    {write-host "Not in DMZ"}
```

Before you ask, I did try `-split (".")` but this doesn't seem to take any effect.

So why does the result come out like `@{IPV4Address=192.9.4.1}`? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Use `-split '\.'`, not `-split '.'`

Comment: All the answers are currently missing the other part of the question which I am sure the OP is still having an issue with. `@{IPV4Address=192.9.4.1}? `

Comment: @Matt You are right, I added an explanation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get the value of the `IPV4Address` property you will have to expand it:

```
$IP4Address = Test-Connection -Computer SERVER -Count 1 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
```

Then you can use the [`.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
if($IPV4Address.Split(".")[1] -eq "9") {
  "In DMZ"
} else {
  "Not in DMZ"
}
```

PS : I usually use `-Count 2` rather than `-Count 1`

Answer (score 3):

The [`-split` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx) takes a *regex pattern*, not a character literal.

In regex, `.` is a wildcard meaning "any one character", resulting in a collection of empty strings (the positions between each character in the input string).

To match a literal dot, escape it with `\`

```
PS C:\> '10.0.122.12' -split '\.'
10
0
122
12
```

Answer (score 3):

You *don't need to split* the IP Address, just use `-match`:

```
if ($IP4Address -match '^\d+\.9\.') 
{
    write-host "In DMZ"
} 
else
{
    write-host "Not in DMZ"
}
```

**Regex:**

```
^\d+\.9\.'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

Your receive the output `@{IPV4Address=192.9.4.1}` because you are selecting the `object`. If you just want to get the string, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$IP4Address = Test-Connection _Computer SERVER -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to show you another approach that is not split based as well as point out the issue you are having with the "ipaddress" object you have. What you are seeing in your variable is an object with an ipaddress property as supposed to a string which is what you are looking for. You need to expand that property or call the property from your object `$IP4Address.Ipaddress`. The former is the easier solution for single properties.

You can cast the result as the type accelerator `[ipaddress]`. This was you can call the method and return the octet you are look to filter on.

```
$IP4Address = Test-Connection -Computer SERVER -Count 1 | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
([ipaddress]$IP4Address).GetAddressBytes()[1]
```

You would need to be careful with this approach as you should also be doing some checking to be sure that `$IP4Address` is not null.

```
if($IP4Address){([ipaddress]$IP4Address).GetAddressBytes()[1]}
```